# Mysql DateTime compare

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table of the following 2 records:

```
descript | start                | end
test 1   | 2011-07-18 14:30:00  | 2011-07-18 17:00:00
test 2   | 2011-07-18 00:00:00  | 2011-07-19 00:00:00
```

When I tried to do a select, I can't seems to retrieve the 2nd result (test 2) which seems like clearly it is dated 19th of July.

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE start >= "2011-07-18 00:00:00" AND end <= "2011-07-18 23:59:59";
```

Would appreciate any advise.

Comment: Your second `WHERE`-clause tells your server to only retrieve data where `end` is <= `2011-07-18 23:59:59`. Since `2011-07-19 00:00:00` is > than `2011-07-18 23:59:59`, it doesn't appear in your resultset.

Comment: ooh man thanks for highlighting, I overlooked that. Any idea how do I do a in-between date range compare then? Like for the above example doing the SELECT query, I'd also like to retrieve the 2nd result because the start date falls in the 18th July range?

Answer (score 5):

"2011-07-19 00:00:00" is **MORE** than "2011-07-18 23:59:59"

By your condition it should be less, so your query does not match `test 2`.

Your `SQL` query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE start >= "2011-07-18 00:00:00" 
AND end <= "2011-07-19 00:00:00";
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, I overlooked that. Any idea how do I do a in-between date range compare then? Like for the above example doing the SELECT query, I'd also like to retrieve the 2nd result because the start date falls in the 18th July range?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this :)

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE start BETWEEN '2011-07-18 00:00:00' AND '2011-07-19 00:00:00' 
AND end BETWEEN '2011-07-18 00:00:00' AND '2011-07-19 00:00:00'
```

This results in the times in between the range you specified for start AND end

Answer (score 1):

you just need to exclude column `end`, like

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE start>="2011-07-18 00:00:00" AND start<="2011-07-18 23:59:59";
```